# Abstract factory to use inject properties c# ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, abstract

I have an Abstract factory like this:

```
public abstract class CustomFactory
{
    [Inject]
    public ICustomService service{ get; set; }
}
```

Every time when I try to access `service`, I get `null`.

Service is registered in Bootstrap and i can access them from non-abstract class

```
kernel.Bind<ICustomService>().To<CustomService>();
```

What is the solution ?

Comment: Could you please share also the code that fails ?

Comment: Furthermore, I didn't get your comment about non-abstract class. You can't instantiate an abstract class. An abstract class should be inherited from a concrete class. So if you have any problem, this should be found in the concrete class that derives from `CustomFactory` class.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example? For instance a simple console application that demonstrates your problem, but with the minimum amount of code possible.